# C# For Loop running beyond scope using uint

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and C#.

When I run this for loop, it iterates beyond 0, and i becomes 4294967295

```
//where loActionList.Count starts at 1
// First time through loop works
// Second time I can see i decrement to 4294967295
// I'm declaring i as uint because loActionList requires it
// and because other vars require it (they are based on an external API)

for (uint i = loActionList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
....
}
```

I can do this:

```
for (int i = (int)loActionList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   IPXC_Action_Goto myvar = (IPXC_Action_Goto)loActionList[(uint)i];
}
```

...but I'd like to know if there is another way to handle this.
Perhaps something that simply prevents the for loop from going beyond 0?

RESOLVED: I ended up using @RonBeyer's suggestion of adding a break with this code `if (i == 0) break;`.

Comment: an unsigned integer, by design can not be negative. It's impossible for the statement `i >= 0` to return false. It instead underflows to its maximum value. Would you be able to up the data type to `long`? It can hold every value `uint` can, while also being capable of negative numbers.

Comment: If you want the loop to stop before it does this, simply update your loop condition to `i > 0`

Comment: You do not really need that big of iterator. You cannot have 4.2 billion of object in the collection. FYI that would take at least 17 gb or ram if it only contain `int`

Comment: What you are experiencing is called "rollover" and it has to do when `i--` is evaluated. In your case `i >= 0` can never be false because unsigned integers are always positive or zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the issue, lets look at a `for` loop with a regular `int`:

```
int i;
for(i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
  Console.Write(i);
}
```

Running that, you'd get `543210` as you'd expect.

However, if you output `i` now, you'd get `-1`. It stopped, because after making `i = -1`, it checked `-1 >= 0`, and then saw that was `false` and aborted.

The problem with `uint` (unsigned integer) is that `0 - 1` on a `uint` give you its max value, since it wraps back around. After doing `0 - 1`, it'll check that and see `BIG_NUMBER_HERE >= 0` is true, so it'll keep going.

There are a couple simple ways to avoid this. Which you use depends on your use case / personal tastes:

- use an `int` instead of a `uint`
- increase your start value by `1` and end at `> 0` instead
- make your condition `i >= 0 && i < BIG_NUMBER_HERE`
- Add `if (i == 0) break;` at the end of the `for` loop to force out if you've hit zero (thanks Ron Beyer).

The `BIG_NUMBER_HERE` would be the `uint` max value. It differs here and there how you get that number, but there should be a constant that will give you that number if you need it.

Comment: You could also add `if (i == 0) break;` to the `for` loop.

Comment: Good answer, and i know this is probalby nitpicky but since its not a Java question but C# maybe change it to Console.Write(i); ?

Comment: @SamMarion Not nitpicky at all. My brain tried to avoid `console.log()`  since it knew that was wrong, and ended up picking the Java version instead. =p Updated.

Comment: @RonBeyer Good call, I'll add that to the list.

Comment: @RonBeyer - I ended up using your suggestion as it allowed me to keep my declarations without having to recast in several places. I'd like to give you credit but you only gave a comment - If you add it as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @wayneh Go ahead and accept this one, no sense in adding a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with sign, but need the cardinality of a `uint`, I suggest going with long.

If the API requires a particular data type such as `uint`, I would cast it for each call, to minimize the damage to your code.

```
for (var i = loActionList.LongCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   IPXC_Action_Goto myvar = (IPXC_Action_Goto)loActionList[(uint)i];
}
```